# not able display details in grid using MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

where I have got one textbox and button and when the user entered a value and the press submit button , that values i need to show in Kendo UI Grid in same view  ..

for this purpose i have done like this .....

this is my model..

```
namespace KendoSampleMVCApp.Models
{
    public class TextBoxGrid
    {
        public string EnteredValue { get; set; }    
        public List<EmployeeDetails> employees;    
    }
    public class EmployeeDetails
    {
        public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string ManagerId { get; set; }    
    }
}
```

and this is my controller

```
namespace KendoSampleMVCApp.Controllers
{
    public class EnterValuesGridController : Controller
    {     
        public ActionResult Index( TextBoxGrid model)
        {
            return View(GetEmployee());
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PostValues(TextBoxGrid model)
        {
            TempData["enteringValue"] = model.EnteredValue;
            return View(model);                
        }    
        public  IEnumerable<EmployeeDetails> GetEmployee()
        {
            string enteredValueId =(string) TempData["enteringValue"];
            string managerId = "M" +enteredValueId;
            List<EmployeeDetails> empdtls = new List<EmployeeDetails>();
            EmployeeDetails em1 = new EmployeeDetails();
            em1.EmployeeId = enteredValueId;
            em1.ManagerId = managerId;
            empdtls.Add(em1);
            return empdtls;
        }    
        public ActionResult Orders_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            return Json(GetOrders().ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }    
        private  IEnumerable<EmployeeDetails> GetOrders()
        {
            return GetEmployee();
        }   
    }
}
```

and this is my view

```
@model KendoSampleMVCApp.Models.TextBoxGrid
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostValues","EnterValuesGrid",FormMethod.Post))
{ 
     <div>
   <fieldset>
        <legend>Enter Textbox Value</legend>

        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.EnteredValue) 
        </div>
        <p>           
            <input type="submit" name="Submitbutton1" value="Submit1" />                     
        </p>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
}    
@model IEnumerable<KendoSampleMVCApp.Models.EmployeeDetails> <-----  error at this line    
<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoSampleMVCApp.Models.EmployeeDetails>()    
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(p => p.EmployeeId).Filterable(false).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ManagerId).Filterable(false).Width(100);        
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Read(read => read.Action("Orders_Read", "EnterValuesGrid"))
     )
  )
}
```

I am getting error at this line `@model IEnumerable<KendoSampleMVCApp.Models.EmployeeDetails>`
saying that

**Parser Error Message: Only one 'model' statement is allowed in a file.**

would any one pls suggest any ideas why i am getting this error ...can't i use two models in same view ....

many thanks ...

**EDIT** : can i do like this In my model...

```
 public class ParentViewModel
 { 
      public EmployeeDetails EmployeeDetails { get; set; }
       public TextBoxGrid TextBoxGrid { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: would any one hav any idea on how to access those one in view ..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is no, you can't use two models in one view. And there is no reason why you should need to. The whole point of a view model is that is designed to store all of the data for the view to which it corresponds.

Create an `EnterValuesViewModel` class and instantiate it with all of the necessary data from both of your business entities. Then type your view to this class.

```
public class EnterValuesViewModel
{
    public string EnteredValue { get; set; }
    public List<EmployeeDetailsViewModel> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeDetailsViewModel
{
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string ManagerId { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model EnterValuesViewModel

@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.EnteredValue)

@foreach(EmployeeDetailsViewModel emp in Model.Employees)
{
    @* Stuff about each employee goes here *@
}
```

Alternatively, look at [partial views](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/105/ASP.NET-MVC-Partial-Views-and-Strongly-Typed-Custom-ViewModels).

Comment: pls look at my edit If i do like that in my model how can i access those ones in my view ...

Comment: sorry i need to access ienumerable items from that EmployeeDetailsViewModel thats why I have mentioned this one `IEnumerable<KendoSampleMVCApp.Models.EmployeeDetails>` do i need to change any thing at this line

Comment: can I remove this line in view `IEnumerable<KendoSampleMVCApp.Models.EmployeeDetails>`

Comment: You don't need to (and can't) bind your view twice. Use `Model.Employees`. If you want, you can create a partial view, strongly type that to `EmployeeDetailsViewModel`. and call that from your main view. It sounds like you need to follow some tutorials.